# Protractor: getting select option status always "displayed" regardless of visibility of select dropdown

Tags: javascript, selenium, automation, protractor

I have select element like this:

```
<select id='mySelect'>
    <option value=0>Monday</option>
    <option value=1>Tuesday</option>
</select>
```

Whenever I use protractor's `isDisplayed()` property to check visibility of option element it always returns true.

```
element.all(by.css('#mySelect option')).first().isDisplayed(); // always return true
```

I'm getting this behavior regardless of clicking on the select element. Ideally it should only return `true` if I click on `<select>` element first then check the visibility.
Any solution ?

Answer (score 1):

`element(by.css('#mySelect')).isDisplayed();` doesn't check the visibility of the options, it checks the visibility of the `<select>` element. You need to target the `<option>` tag

```
element(by.css('#mySelect option')).isDisplayed();
```

And to check all options

```
var options = element.all(by.css('#mySelect option'));

options.each((option, index) => {
    option.isDisplayed();
});
```

As an alternative you can check for visibility by checking the element offsets

```
var option = element(by.css('#mySelect option'));
var isDisplayed = option.offsetWidth > 0 && option.offsetHeight > 0;
```

Comment: Updated my description. Sorry for that.
in your code  `option.isDisplayed()` is returning always true for me.

Comment: @JunaidNazir sometimes `isDisplayed()` is not 100%, I added an alternative to the answer.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use protractor ExpectedConditions `visibilityOf` ([doc](https://www.protractortest.org/#/api?view=ProtractorExpectedConditions.prototype.visibilityOf)) instead of `isDisplayed`.

> An expectation for checking that an element is present on the DOM of a page and visible. Visibility means that the element is not only displayed but also has a height and width that is greater than 0.

It is a combination of `presenceOf` ([doc](https://www.protractortest.org/#/api?view=ProtractorExpectedConditions.prototype.presenceOf)) and `isDisplayed`.

Comment: Already tried this one. But the native dropdown of `<select>` is returning always true for both `isPresent()` & `isDisplayed()`. :(